# Spark history server and clearing history

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

What is the best way to get away with the History Server entries. My cluster has lot many execution which show up as Application Ids. I know these are occupying significant amount of hard disk space in HDFS file system (i am assuming).

Actually, the heap memory usage of History server is continuing to increasing with time as more and more executions are happening in the cluster.

I have changed two things in Spark configuration: 
1) Retained App Count (Spark conf)
spark.history.retainedApplications (from 50 to 5)

2) Yarn Conf - Java Heap Size of JobHistory Server in Bytes - This was 128 MB earlier and I increased to 256, then to 920. History server wasn't starting due to heap memory issue until I put 920.

Can I do more cleanup so that Spark history server doesn't take so much memory. I am not interested in the history at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways which I can think of is to write another custom job which can extract spark history and store it in cloud/any external storage(ex : s3) . You can add this job as a dependent job to your application so that whenever your application executes, the clean up job also runs as the last step. For instance, If you are executing your job through EMR, then you could add that job as a dependent step so that whenever your job completes, the cleanup job will trigger and your application history can be stored in S3

Comment: I thought of doing this tactical thing of removing files/folders in the hadoop file system directly under the folder where history server files are present. Is it a good idea? Since i am in development cycle, I am not keen on maintaining the history.

Comment: Do you mean writing a script to do the removal or manually ? . If its a one-time job, then doing it manually makes sense. Otherwise I would suggest you to write a script to do that. I would also suggest that backing up history is better than deleting since you might need to re-visit history incase of any  issues